# Similar select boxes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, select

Is this possible to create several select boxes in Rails with the same options? And then create an object based on those selected values?

For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible? Yes, but such usage is dependent on your application and why you'd want to use it in the first place. Also, in order to use something like this, you have to ensure that the select fields don't have the same name, otherwise one would override the other.

Comment: Even if they have different names, what should I do next with params? For instance, after selection I have such params in my controller **object => { "subtype_1" => "1", "subtype_2" => "2" }** How can I proceed with this? I mean it would be foolish to add **params.require(:object).permit(:subtype_1, :subtype_2 ...)** to object_params

Comment: My question would be what are you trying to achieve with this? A good example is Paypal which returns all the items paid for in the format of `item_1, item_2...` and when fetching these, you'd probably have to loop through. However, a better/cleaner approach is to have a subtype model as a nested_attribute of another model, that way you could just do: `params.permit(subtypes_attributes: [:subtype_id])`. Don't know your specific use case but these are just my 2 cents